# Question from Indian olympiad

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, contest-math

> If four real numbers a, b, c, x satisfy $abc\neq 0$ and
>
> $$\frac{xb+\left(1-x\right)c}{a}=\frac{xc+\left(1-x\right)a}{b}=\frac{xa+\left(1-x\right)b}{c}$$
>
> then either a = b = c, or a + b + c = 0

---

#### Here is my attempt

------- is the part which can be filled by symmetry

[image]

The question is why am I getting the condition which is supposed was not true, also initially I divided by $a-b$ so $a=b$ doesn't make sense now???

I don't want a new solution to this question, I want to know why my solution is giving me weird results

Comment: The equation after the third implication sign ($\implies$) is wrong.  You should get $$\lambda\left(a^2+b^2+c^2-y\right)+y^2=\lambda y(a+b+c-{\color{red}y})+\frac{abc}{y}\,.$$  And your attempt (even if you corrected that line) seems incomplete.  You should first try to see that if any two of $a$, $b$, and $c$ are equal, then all of them are equal.  From what you did, you could only conclude that $a=b$, $b=c$, $c=a$, or $a+b+c=0$.

Answer (score -1):

You assumed that $a,$ $b$ and $c$ are different numbers and you got a contradiction.

It ends the proof!

I like the following way:

Let $$\frac{xb+\left(1-x\right)c}{a}=\frac{xc+\left(1-x\right)a}{b}=\frac{xa+\left(1-x\right)b}{c}=k.$$
Thus, $$bx-cx=ka-c$$
$$cx-ax=kb-a$$ and
$$ax-bx=kc-b,$$ which gives
$$0=k(a+b+c)-(a+b+c),$$
which gives $$a+b+c=0$$ or $$k=1.$$

For $k=1$ we obtain:
$$(b-c)x=a-c,$$
$$(c-a)x=b-a$$ and
$$(a-b)x=c-b.$$
Now, let $a\neq b$.

Thus, $c\neq a$ and from here $b\neq c$.

Thus, $$\frac{a-c}{b-c}=\frac{b-a}{c-a}=\frac{c-b}{a-b},$$ which gives
$$(a-b)^2=(a-c)(c-b),$$ $$(a-c)^2=(a-b)(b-c)$$ and
$$(b-c)^2=(a-b)(c-a),$$ which gives that $c$ is placed between $a$ and $b$, $b$ is placed between $a$ and $c$ and $a$ is placed between $b$ and $c$, which is impossible and we got a contradiction.

Id est, $a=b$ and we obtain: $$a=b=c.$$

Comment: I didn't ask for a new solution, I want to know why my solution is giving me weird results

Comment: @Raunit singh I added something. See now.